# Equivalent of this Python random number generator in C++?

Tags: c++, python, random

Just switch from Python to C++ and I begin to re-write my Python tools in C++ for better understanding, but can't solve this one...

This function will generate range of random numbers, for example "randomRange(12)" may return range of 12 numbers like "823547896545"

Python:

```
  def randomRange(n):
        range_start = 10**(n-1)
        range_end = (10**n)-1
        return randint(range_start, range_end)

  number = randomRange(12)
```

C++:

```
  int n;
  int randomRange(n){
        int range_start = ?
        int range_end = ?
        int result = ?(range_start, range_end);
        return (result);
  };

  int number = randomRange(12);
```

I can't find equivalent for question marks " ? "

Comment: the power function is std::pow, and there are more than one way of writing random numbers generator, depending on requirements, you can check this article: http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_TR1_random.html

Comment: Thanks for article, I have a lot to learn!

Comment: Beware that you probably won't be able to fit 12 digits into an int on most systems.

Comment: @user786653, so I need to use 'Float' or 'Double' instead?

Comment: @NEX: Or a `long long` or a library with arbitrary integer precision math, or maybe you should just use a smaller range. It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to generate X range of numbers, from Min. 3 to Max. 12, depend on user input. but seems like there are no easy way to do it and I have to use libraries instead!!

Comment: @NEX: On _most_ computers, char holds 2 digits, short is 4 digits, int is 9 digits, long long is 19 digits.  float holds 6 digits, and double holds 16.  If you need more, you need a library

Comment: @Nex -- the simplistic answer you used in Python kept you blissfully unaware of the theory, fortunately C++ will require you to study the subject.

Comment: @NEX: C++ requires libraries for pretty much everything, so much so, that one comes built-in with every compiler.  Yes: get used to using libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have trouble getting good randomness with high values of n, but:

```
#include <math.h>         // for pow()
#include <stdlib.h>       // for drand48()

long randomRange(int n)
{
    // our method needs start and size of the range rather 
    // than start and end.
    long range_start = pow(10,n-1);
    long range_size = pow(10,n)-range_start;
    // we expect the rand48 functions to offer more randomness
    // than the more-well-known rand() function. drand48()
    // gives you a double-precision float in 0.0-1.0, so we 
    // scale up by range_size and and to the start of the range.
    return range_start + long(drand48() * range_size);
};
```

Here's another approach. On 32-bit platforms, you can only do 9 digits in an int, so we'll make the function return a double, and generate a string of ASCII digits then convert:

```
#include <math.h>         // for pow()
#include <stdlib.h>       // for atof()

// arbitrary limit
const int MAX_DIGITS = 24;

double randomRange(int n)
{
    char bigNumString[ MAX_DIGITS+1 ];
    if (n > MAX_DIGITS)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // first digit is 1-9
    bigNumString[0] = "123456789"[rand()%9];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        // subsequent digits can be zero
        bigNumString[i] = "0123456789"[rand()%10];
    }
    // terminate the string
    bigNumString[i] = 0;
    // convert it to float
    return atof(bigNumString);
};
```

Comment: `lrand48` isn't a standard function, and isn't universally available. Unfortunately.

Comment: Great, lots of answers and I'm confused, better check all of them to see which one actually works!

Comment: The `rand48` family is also considered obsolete.

Comment: NEX, you should be able to substitute `rand() % range_size` for `drand48() * range_size` if you're keeping n below 6 or so. You'll have to find a library that provides very wide random numbers to get good results beyond that.

Comment: Exactly @Russell, this is what I'm trying to do now, as none of the examples works like Python version, result is much different. Thanks

Comment: Are you hoping to get the same sequence of rands that you would from Python, or just numbers in the right range? What are you planning to do with these numbers?

Comment: Thank you Russell, I accept your answer because it's closer to what I need, and Also you (with only 2,163 reputation) are way more intelligent than those smart... with 20K fake-reputation!

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the facilities in boost:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html#boost_random.tutorial.generating_integers_in_a_range

There are also similar features in C++11:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

```
int randomRange(n)
{
    int range_start = (int)pow(10, n-1);
    int range_end = (int)pow(10, n) - 1;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(range_start, range_end);
    return dist(gen);
}
```

Note that you can get much better performance by moving all but the `dist(gen)` into an initialization function which is only called once.

Comment: Thank you Mark, but I'm new to C++ and I don't want to use external libraries for now.

Comment: I love C++, but never imagined that I have to do all this things, just to generate range of 12 numbers!!! :) (this is quite frustrating for a Python user!)

Comment: Don't worry - as a Python user, you'll grow to despise C++, as you should.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have just [rand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) which you can bend to your will:

```
int result = (rand() % (range_end - range_start)) + range_start;
```

To explain, rand() generates a random number across a subset of the integer values. You can use modulo lo limit the range of the numbers, then use your start value to provide an offset.

(Also be sure to [seed the random number generator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/))

**Note**
Rand apparently is a pretty lousy random number generator (I had no idea). See the comments.

Comment: Note that using the modulus like this will skew the distribution. Python's implementation is likely much better in this regard.

Comment: The `rand` function isn't guaranteed to have enough range to be useful in all cases; Microsoft's in particular will only give you 0 to 32767. If `range_end - range_start` is larger than this you're going to have holes in the range that can't be hit, and even if it's smaller but not by much you'll get skewed probabilities.

Comment: you got a pretty lousy random number generator, while there are pretty good standard ones.

Comment: Your problem isn't really rand, but the fact that you're using the mod function without making sure to fix the distribution (ie if `range_end - range_start` isn't luckily a dividend of the largest value the random generator can generate it's skewed). You usually fix that by rejecting values in the range [MAX_VAL / n * n, MAX_VAL). And yes that means that in the worst case you reject 50% of all randomly generated numbers (which number's the worst case is left as an exercise for readers ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Truly i don't know what is the algorithm to generate random numbers in python but in C++ isn't good because the frequency of repetition is too much. I recommend to you use mersenne twister algorithm you can [download](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wagnerr/MersenneTwister.html) library and you will see more things about in this [page](http://www.qbrundage.com/michaelb/pubs/essays/random_number_generation.html).

Comment: As some people say the way to get a random number in C++ isn't a good  because it is a pretty lousy random number generator. I shared the posibility to implement mersenne twister or use the library although i know the man don't want to use a extra library.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
unsigned long long randomRange(unsigned int n){
    static bool first = true;
    if (first)
         srand((unsigned int)time(nullptr)); //seed the generator the first time
    //as others say, std::pow to get the range
    double range_start = std::pow(10.0, n-1.0);
    double range_end = std::pow(10.0, double(n))-1.0;
    unsigned long long range = range_end-range_start;
    //generate a random number between 0 and 2^64 (minimum)
    unsigned long long result 
        = rand()*RAND_MAX*RAND_MAX*RAND_MAX
        + rand()*RAND_MAX*RAND_MAX
        + rand()*RAND_MAX
        + rand();
    //force it into range.
    return unsigned long long(result % range + range_start);
};

unsigned long long number = randomRange(12);
```

This is simple, (and I use something like this all the time), but rand() is not the most even distribution, and the use of modulo in the last step skews results even more toward lower numbers.  Also, since it calls rand() *four* times, it might be slower than many solutions, and since I make minimal assumptions about RAND_MAX, it might not be optimal (though.  However, this is a simple solution that is portable. (works on windows/linux/whatever), and will work as long as n is between 1 and ~17.  Above ~17,  it will only pick numbers in the bottom of the range, but since 64-bit long long only holds ~19.26 digits anyway, I don't think it'll be an issue.